# simple_nested_form_for not showing association validation with select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, nested-forms

I am using simple_form along with the nested_form gems. The simple_form validations are show for the parent form but are not showing for an association within the nested form.

**View**

```
#_form.html.erb
<%= simple_nested_form_for( @repair ) do |r| %>
....
<%= r.simple_fields_for :repair_items do |f| %>
<%= f.association :repair_type, label_method: :repair_type_label, value_method: :id, include_blank: true, label: "Type"%>
```

**Model**

```
#repair_item.rb
validates :repair_type_id, :presence => true
```

**Controller**

```
#repairs_controller.rb
def create
  @repair = Repair.new(params[:repair])
  if @repair.save
    redirect_to(repairs_path, :notice => 'Repair Created.')
  else
    @repair.repair_items.new(params[:repair][:repair_items_attributes]["0"].except(:_destroy))
    render :new
  end
end
```

**Edit**

I failed to mention that the association within the nested form is displayed using the select2 js plugin. This may be a factor as to why the Rails validations are not showing???

Answer (score 0):

In you model add inverse_of

```
class Repair < ActiveRecord::base
 has_many :repair_types, inverse_of: :repair
end

class RepairType < ActiveRecord::base
 belongs_to :repair, inverse_of: repair_types
end
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've been trying to figure this out before asking for clarification but have had no luck. I think the repair_items relationship needs to be involved. Repair has_many repair_items. A repair_item belongs to a repair and a repair_type (which has_many repair_items). I have set up inverse_of in all 3 models with no success.